# Supertypes of the class can't be resolved

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I have a module with custom dialog which extends `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog`. My module has next dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

but I still get next error:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class myapp.com.ScrollableBottomSheetDialog, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog
```

But there no any `import` erros inside of my custom class...

any ideas? any similar cases?

Answer (score 0):

Strange situation. I have also 1.0.0 version, but everything is okay. Try to "Invalidate caches/Restart". But I am using BottomSheetDialogFragment rather than BottomSheetDialog.